# Is it possible to install/create goup channel on theme install automatically

Tags: channel-entries, channel

I am looking to provide my client with the theme.

Is it possible to install/create group channel on theme install automatically.

For eg: In wordpress, We can create custom theme options and meta fields within posts and pages. Similarly is it possible that I can code the extra field portion in my code so that client can simply install theme and create page content rather then creating channels and fields at backend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty certain this isn't possible. Themes have been tried before in Expression Engine, but there's a reason they never really took hold. Quite simply, there are so many different ways to build an EE site and structure the channels, that theming is almost impossible.

Word Press doesn't have a multi-channel approach like EE, hence theming being much easier. If you simply want to provide your client with a theme and a turnkey website, I'd say EE is the wrong platform for what you need.

EE really needs to be set up based on your clients requirements then linked to your page templates. From here your client can work with the content using their own *bespoke* theme that you would setup for them.